# How to determine the RAM requirements to use Redis Object Cache to optimize WordPress performance

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redis

**Description**
Website is based on WordPress and currently hosted on a shared hosting... It has some simple landing pages with a webform for lead generation, with a few otpimized .webp images and embeded YouTube Video

Gravity Forms, Yoast, HFCM for GA and Google Ads code insertion, no extra plugins used, and the theme is lightweight and doesn't have any overheads.

**Issue**
The issue is initial server response which takes a way too high time

**My question**
On a 2 GB RAM and 2VCPUs VPS with SSD is it possible to use Redis Object Cache to optimize WordPress performance? will use nginx phpfpm

If yes? what parameters should be taken into the account? No? What's the minimum memory requirement?

Any other option?

Best

**Tried all this but not helpful**,
W3Total Cache, but it's best with some object cache and not available on shared hosting account

Free CloudFlare which is available with the hosting platform but didn't help much.

Nitropack is good, but don't want to pay month on month, will buy a reserved instead for upfront payment on good discount.

There are limitations on a shared hosting account and for that reason can't install anything like Redis or Memcache.

Answer (score 0):

I think moving to a VPS would help you fix server response time. But you need to use the correct setup. In my opinion, best setup would be,

- LEMP Stack without a control panel
- WP-Rocket plugin for generating static html files
- [Rocket-nginx](https://github.com/SatelliteWP/rocket-nginx) for serving html files without executing PHP
- Redis-cache for object caching
- Cloudfront for serving static files.
- PHP opcache

This specific setup will allow you to serve your WordPress site from even a 1GB server. If it's as simple as you claim. Since WP-Rocket and Rocket-nginx generate and serve html files instead of executing PHP on every page load, there won't be much stress on the server. I got my server setup the similar way using [this guy's service](https://vpsfix.us/fiverr/wordpress-installation). So credits to him.

Cloudflare is also a good solution. But you have to be on their pro plan to really benefit from it. I was with them before I moved to above mentioned setup. But it was a bit expensive for my site.

Answer (score 0):

Redis requires sufficient RAM to function well. Given your 2GB of RAM, which is also shared with your WordPress stack, consider allocating 50% or less of the total memory to Redis.

To prevent memory exhaustion, it is essential to properly configure eviction policy, swap configuration, and persistence.

Here is a basic configuration to get started:

- maxmemory 1024mb
- maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
- vm-swap-file /dev/null
- vm-max-memory 0
- save ""
- appendonly no